# Compile and run Groovy on Linux server

Tags: java, linux, groovy

I'm trying to move my Groovy project to a server with no Eclipse. In order to minimize the uncertainty I compiled my project in Eclipse (on my PC) and copied the project(with all .class compiled in /bin) to the server in a whole. After that I kept meeting the error: 
`Error: Could not find or load main class edu.xxx.textrank.TrendAnalysis`

This is how I ran my code:

All .groovy and .java are in folder .../TextRank/src/edu/xxx/textrank/, all compiled .class files are in folder  .../TextRank/bin/edu/xxx/textrank/, and all dependent .jar files are in folder .../TextRank/lib/. In directory .../TextRank/bin I ran `java -cp ../lib/*.jar:. edu/xxx/textrank/KeywordExtractor` and met the error. TrendAnalysis.class was compiled from TrendAnalysis.groovy and there are also some auxillary .class compiled from closures in groovy: 
`TrendAnalysis$_allPeriodKeywordStudy_closure1.class      TrendAnalysis$_certainPeriodKeywordStudy_closure3.class
TrendAnalysis$_allPeriodKeywordStudy_closure2.class`

However, things are not quite same for those .class files compiled from .java. For example I was able to run `Patterns.class` which was compiled from `Patterns.java` without inner classes by the same command

`[xuch@xxxxx bin]$ java -cp ../lib/*.jar:. edu/xxx/textrank/Patterns
abcdefghijk`

I'm wondering what could be the real culprit. Can I just run the .class files without re-compiling them on another server? Or am I able to just run the main .class without calling all the innerclass files (auto-generated by Groovy)?

Any suggestion and help is appreciated! Also quick solutions will help (like how to compile all things into an executable .jar etc). Thanks a lot!!

Edit: One important thing to mention, all my .java and .groovy are in package edu.xxx.textrank. In other words they all have `package edu.xxx.textrank;`

Comment: if your classes are in /edu/... and you start your code in /bin, then your classpath must contain `..` and not `.`?

Comment: @cfrick I'm in the path /bin so "." is enough. Also the Patterns.class was able to run.

Comment: then you have omitted some information in your question. is your Pattern class also in one of the jars? if your cwd is /bin and your .classes are in ../edu/... relative to your cwd, then -cp . will _not_ find your classes.

Comment: @cfrick Good catch! Sorry I forgot to mention my .java and .groovy are all in `package edu.xxx.textrank`. Thanks for reminding me

Comment: the packages only mean, that you have to provide the proper directory hierarchy.  please have a look here https://gist.github.com/christoph-frick/566a8cf120df0f465f27 and see how the `.` there is wrong relative in bin.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks you found a mistake I made in my path. I moved all source files to Textrank/src/edu/xxx/textrank folder, but the problem persists. I've edited the question too. Now all source files(.java and .groovy) are in TextRank/src/edu/xxx/textrank, all .class in TextRank/bin/edu/xxx/textrank. Please kindly help. Now I'm pretty sure no issue with the path itself.

Comment: my example there is the proof that what you describe does basically work. could you please try to follow these steps and provide a minimal failing example for your case? maybe you find the original problem while doing so, or we get an example, that we can actually look into.

Comment: I agree that it partly works. But I think there are still more possibilities than I could find the culprit directly by one test. Your comment makes sense and I'll try to extract them one by one to see what could have caused the problem. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: As first step you should build and test your project using gradle.(or similar)  Once that works on your windows machine, it will probably works everywhere

Comment: @Jayan Actually as a quick workaround I built everything into an executable jar and run it on my server. But still I'm curious what went wrong so I'll spend more time testing it out in the coming several days.